# Ошибка sql join

Tags: sql

```
$q = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM comments FULL JOIN users ON comments.user_id=users.login WHERE parent_com_id='0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $lim;");
```

есть 2 таблицы, 1 - comments содержит ID юзера. 2 - users. пытаюсь соединить их, выходит ошибка ниже в mysql_fetch_array()

вывод как я полагаю в обоих случаях будет таким:

```
while($allinone = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
echo 'текст из первой таблицы'.$allinone['text_comm'];
echo 'текст из второй таблицы'.$allinone['avatar'];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы соединяете таблицы, то все перед всеми названиями столбцов нужно писать имя таблицы. В вашем случае без имени таблицы остались столбцы parent_com_id и id. То есть должно получиться что-то такое

```
... WHERE comments.parent_com_id='0' ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT $lim
```

Comment: @mountpoint, при выводе точно так же? $allinone['comments.text_comm']

Comment: Дописал вывод ошибок, показало "Unknown column 'comments.user_id' in 'on clause'"

Comment: @singmen, я не знаю какие у вас там имена столбцов в таблицах. Я написал от фонаря, чтобы вы смысл уловили. Приведите структуру этих таблиц, тогда можно точно запрос построить

Comment: @mountpoint, заменил FULL JOIN на LEFT и заработало, твое так же дописал, благодарю =)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL не поддерживает соединение [FULL JOIN](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_full_join_and_mysql.html).